# Do most muslims go to jannah without punishment?

Tags: jannah, jahannam, day-of-judgement, hereafter

I am talking about muslims from all ummahs: Musa, Isa, Ibrahim, Muhammad, and all prophets Allah sent. Do most go to jannah without jahannam?

Comment: The answer is we don't know. Judgement is up to Allah and we know and trust he'll be Just.

Answer (score 0):

Prophets (a.s) will go to jannah as they are selected people of Allah who themselves call others to straight path.

> And whoever obeys Allah and the Messenger will be in the company of
> those blessed by Allah: the prophets, the people of truth, the
> martyrs, and the righteous—what honourable company!
>
> Quran 4:69

Quran says those who obeys Allah and messenger will be with prophets, so they will be in jannah. Also in jannah will be people of truth, martyrs and the righteous. We cannot for sure know who all will be in this group, some we can know clearly from their actions but some we don't even know. Our duty is to strive to join this group of righteous people.

About entering Jannah without punishment. It is upto Allah to decide. There is a reference in Quran in which says everyone pass by Hell but God will save the righteous from it.

> By your Lord ˹O Prophet˺! We will surely gather them along with the
> devils, and then set them around Hell on their knees. Then We will
> certainly begin by dragging out of every group the ones most defiant
> to the Most Compassionate. And We truly know best who is most
> deserving of burning in it. There is none of you who will not pass
> over it. ˹This is˺ a decree your Lord must fulfil. Then We will
> deliver those who were devout, leaving the wrongdoers there on their
> knees.
>
> https://quran.com/19/68-72